# Rails not differentiating between two resources nested in the same namespaces

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, friendly-id

I have two types of products that are nested under the same categories. The routes I have setup are

```
resources :categories, path: '/', only: [:show] do
  resources :subcategories, path: '/', only: [:show] do
    resources :amazon_products, path: '/', only: [:show]
    resources :other_products, path: '/', only: [:show]
  end
end
```

which I was previously accessing using this link

```
<%= link_to "View Product Page", [product.collection, product.category, product.subcategory, product], class: 'product__link' %>
```

which that resulted in something like this url after `friendly_id` finished with it

> /cleansers/face-wash-and-cleansers/blemish-remedy-acne-treatment-gelee-cleanser

The issue is that the link only resolves for amazon_products and I'm not sure how to make it differentiate between the two. I think the problem is in the way I am referencing the path since when I enter rails routes in the console, I can see the two different paths there like so

```
category_subcategory_amazon_product
GET    :category_id/:subcategory_id/:id(.:format)
amazon_products#show

category_subcategory_other_product
GET    /:collection_id/:category_id/:subcategory_id/:id(.:format)
other_products#show
```

I tried specifically referencing the other product path using the link

```
category_subcategory_other_product_path(product.category, product.subcategory, product)
```

but it is giving me an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound since its still looking in the wrong controller

```
app/controllers/amazon_products_controller.rb:5:in `show'
```

How do I tell rails to differentiate between these two resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you boil it down, Rails routes are relatively simple patterns that match URIs and dispatch requests to the proper controller/method.

If you had specified your nested routes in their basic form:

```rb
resources :categories, only: [:show] do
  resources :subcategories, only: [:show] do
    resources :amazon_products, only: [:show]
    resources :other_products, only: [:show]
  end
end
```

The resulting URI patterns for the product level would look like:

```
/categories/<id>/subcategories/<id>/amazon_products/<id>
/categories/<id>/subcategories/<id>/other_products/<id>
```

Admittedly verbose, but obviously distinct, patterns.

The issue is that you are using `path: '/'` on the resources to remove everything unique about the resource routes. So, your product-level route patterns are:

```
category_subcategory_amazon_product: /<id>/<id>/<id>
category_subcategory_other_product: /<id>/<id>/<id>
```

Since the two patterns are identical, Rails falls back to the time honoured practice of matching the first one defined. You can demonstrate that for yourself by swapping `:other_products` so it is first; its controller will then be the one always invoked.

NB: It doesn't matter that you are using friendly-id -- that just changes what the IDs look like to the user, not the basic route pattern.

The solution is to simply reintroduce some uniqueness, at least at the product level.

```rb
resources :categories, path: '/', only: [:show] do
  resources :subcategories, path: '/', only: [:show] do
    resources :amazon_products, path: 'amazon', only: [:show]
    resources :other_products, path: 'other', only: [:show]
  end
end
```

The result will be route patterns that Rails can actually distinguish:

```
category_subcategory_amazon_product: /<id>/<id>/amazon/<id>
category_subcategory_other_product: /<id>/<id>/other/<id>
```